# Calling data from JSON file using AJAX

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, parsing

I am trying to load some data from my JSON file using AJAX. The file is called external-file.json. Here is the code, it includes other parts that haven't got to do with the data loading.The part I'm not sure of begins in the getViaAjax funtion. I can't seem to find my error.

```
function flip(){
    if(vlib_front.style.transform){
        el.children[1].style.transform = "";
        el.children[0].style.transform = "";
    } else {
        el.children[1].style.transform = "perspective(600px) rotateY(-180deg)";
        el.children[0].style.transform = "perspective(600px) rotateY(0deg)";
    }
}
var vlib_front = document.getElementById('front');
var el = document.getElementById('flip3D');

el.addEventListener('click', flip);

var word = null; var explanation = null;

var i=0;

function updateDiv(id, content) {
    document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = content;
    document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = content;
}
updateDiv('the-h',word[i]);
updateDiv('the-p',explanation[i])

function counter (index, step){
    if (word[index+step] !== undefined) {
        index+=step;
        i=index;
        updateDiv('the-h',word[index]);
        updateDiv('the-p',explanation[index]);
    }      
}

var decos = document.getElementById('deco');
decos.addEventListener('click', function() {
    counter(i,-1);
}, false);
var incos = document.getElementById('inco');
incos.addEventListener('click', function() {
    counter(i,+1);
}, false);
function getViaAjax("external-file.json", callback) { // url being the url to external File holding the json
    var r = new XMLHttpRequest();
    r.open("GET", "external-file.json", true);
    r.onload = function() {
        if(this.status < 400 && this.status > 199) {

            if(typeof callback === "function")
                callback(JSON.parse(this.response));
        } else {
            console.log("err");// server reached but gave shitty status code}
        };
    }
    r.onerror = function(err) {console.log("error Ajax.get "+url);console.log(err);}

    r.send();
}

function yourLoadingFunction(jsonData) {
    word = jsonData.words;
    explanation = jsonData.explanation;
    updateDiv('the-h',word[i]);
    updateDiv('the-p',explanation[i])
    // then call whatever it is to trigger the update within the page
}

getViaAjax("external-file.json", yourLoadingFunction)
```

Comment: What is the value of `i` when the AJAX call completes? Using a global variable like this seems like a bad idea.

Comment: In the declaration of a function, parameters must be identifiers. `"external-file.json"` is not a valid parameter.

Comment: @light Show the correct way to do it in an anaswer.

Comment: To adequately give an answer, we need to first understand the question. The way the question is phrased, I don't think anyone knows what it's really asking about. Before OP provides more clarity on what error he is facing, we can only point out the obvious minor mistakes in his code.

Comment: @light [This is my web app.](http://langbook.co/testicles-1-2-flashcards/) The cards are supposed to display the values that I have in the `.json` file. As you can see, they don't. That is my problem.

Comment: @ArielHalilajAl your link contains errors in JS even before hitting `getViaAjax()`, particularly: `word is null` at Line 58. It would seem like the problem is nothing to do with the code you provided at all. Also, please do provide an MCVE: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

Comment: This is my original [code.](https://jsfiddle.net/arielhg/yr2x109m/) **All** I am trying to do is put the values in an external file in order to save loading time.

Answer (score 1):

As @light said, this:

```
function getViaAjax("external-file.json", callback) { // url being the url to external File holding the json
  var r = new XMLHttpRequest();
  r.open("GET", "external-file.json", true);
```

Should be:

```
function getViaAjax(url, callback) { // url being the url to external File holding the json
  var r = new XMLHttpRequest();
  r.open("GET", url, true);
```

Comment: should I give the url the value of the String "external-file.json" ?

Comment: that's what you are doing here: getViaAjax("external-file.json", yourLoadingFunction)

Comment: @ArielHalilajAl please edit the code in your question, and tell us what you mean by "it doesn't work". http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve <-- Read this, particularly under "Verifiable".

Comment: I am making a web application. [Flashcards](http://langbook.co/testicles-1-2-flashcards/). I am trying to store the values in an external file and call them only when I need to in order to save loading time.

Answer (score 0):

I built up a quick sample that I can share that might help you isolate your issue. Stand this up in a local `http-server` of your choice and you should see `JSON.parse(xhr.response)` return a javascript array containing two objects.

There are two files

1. data.json
2. index.html

**data.json**

```
    [{
        "id":1,
        "value":"foo"
    },
    {
        "id":2,
        "value":"bar"
    }]
```

**index.html**

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body onload="so.getJsonStuffs()">
        <h1>so.json-with-ajax</h1>
        <script type="application/javascript">
        var so = (function(){

            function loadData(data){
               var list = document.createElement("ul");
               list.id = "data-list";
               data.forEach(function(element){
                   var item = document.createElement("li");
                   var content = document.createTextNode(JSON.stringify(element));

                   item.appendChild(content);
                   list.appendChild(item);
               });
               document.body.appendChild(list);
           }

            var load = function()
            {
                console.log("Initializing xhr");
                var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

                xhr.onload = function(e){
                    console.log("response has returned");
                    if(xhr.status > 200
                    && xhr.status < 400) {
                        var payload = JSON.parse(xhr.response);
                        console.log(payload);
                        loadData(payload);
                    }
                }
                var uri = "data.json";
                console.log("opening resource request");
                xhr.open("GET", uri, true);
                xhr.send();
            }

            return {
                getJsonStuffs : load
            }
        })();
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Running will log two Javascript objects to the Dev Tools console as well as add a `ul` to the DOM containing a list item for every object inside the `data.json` array

Comment: I think this is very much different of what I'm trying to do. I am making a [flashcards web app](http://langbook.co/testicles-1-2-flashcards/) and what I want to do is store the values of the `words` and `explanation` in an external file in order to save page loading time.

Comment: @ArielHalilajAl It's actually not "very different" than what you are doing with your code, but it is different from what your added description says that you are wanting to accomplish.  It's strange to me that you are trying to use an xhr to write to a local file. From reading your code, I had assumed you were simply wanting to read data from the file.  Writing to an arbitrary file on the end-user's machine is not going to be a viable solution for you.  My suggestion is that you use the localStorage API and stuff in a stringified version of your resource so that you can work with it in json.

Comment: ...probably better than that even would be to stuff your resource file into the IndexedDB and let *it* interface with the file system for performing your file io.  I haven't needed to work with it in a while, so you'll probably want to research the implementations in the browsers you are wanting to support.

Comment: The code is written by some guy on Reddit whom I asked for help. I am simply trying to read data from the file, but I'm becoming ever more confused. Could you provide the easiest solution in your opinion?

Comment: @Ariel ...if you are wanting to read data from an external .json file, my sample will work to show you how to do that.  If you're wanting to *write* to an external .json file -and it seems as if you do-, your task becomes more complicated.  You do not (and should not) have direct control over the file system from the browser.  The HTML5 Filesystem API was started by Google as an approach to allowing apps a sandbox on the file system for performing file io, but their idea never took on (mostly because better alternatives already existed) [continued]

Comment: ...IndexedDB is an in-browser technology that allows you to store arbitrary data, which in turn, writes to files on the user machine.  You can interact with it and it can perform your file io.  You can use an xhr over top of IndexedDB so that your interface is to a "resource" that you /GET /POST /PUT /DELETE to, and let your internal callbacks perform the actual work against the record in IndexedDB.  Does that make sense?

Comment: To me it sounds overcomplicated. Please take a look at the original [code.](https://jsfiddle.net/arielhg/yr2x109m/) **All** I want to do is put the values in an external file in order to save loading time.

Comment: As I illustrated in my answer, if you have a stock list of values that you want to make available to the client, drop them in a json file just like I demonstrated in my sample.  If you are wanting to retrieve items from the server and cache them in a json file on the client, you're going about this wrong.  Unless a cookie would suffice, you will need to use the HTML 5 Local Storage API or something more robust in order to write data client-side to make it accessible for future retrieval.

Comment: Yes but I'm not sure how to implement your answer in my existing code. Could you please edit my jsfiddle?

Comment: I'm not sure how it can get simpler than the code I provided in my answer.  All I did with it is load arbitrary json data with an xhr, which is what I thought you were trying to do.I output the data to the console and appended the parsed values to the DOM so that you could see that it works without having to inspect the code thoroughly.I do not have access to execute jsfiddles through my corporate firewall, or I would try to help more.But it really does seem like you're looking for someone to deliver you working software rather than answer your question.

Comment: It's just that I am too much of an amateur. I will try to understand your answer and thank you for your help.

Comment: @ArielHalilajAl I can't verify that everything else with your sample is correct, but one glaring error is in your signature for `function getViaAjax` You declared it to be `function getViaAjax("external-file.json", callback)` and this will not work. You have to use a variable name here in place of your filename, but from your other comments, it seems as if you've already tried this to no avail.